# Adding TableRow Dynamically to TableLayout in xml

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

Although this looks a lot repeated question but first time for me. I searched all over and could not get the result and ended up posting here.

I am creating a table dynamically of which the `TableLayout` part is written in xml part.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/componentA">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tl_componentA">


        </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I created an object for the table

```
TableLayout tableLayoutA;
tableLayoutA= (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tl_componentA);
```

Now I tried to add a row dynamically from here onwards as

```
createTableRowColumn(tableLayoutA);
```

Functions Related are

```
private void createTableRowColumn(TableLayout tableLayout){

        TableRow tableRow1= new TableRow(this.context);
        tableRow1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        setTableRowColumnProperty(tableRow1);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow1);
    }
```

private void setTableRowColumnProperty(TableRow tableRow){

```
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams= new TableRow.LayoutParams(70, 40);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

I did all this and nothing showed me in the emulater. But when I gave same structure in xml mannually then thing was working well.

For this reason i tried something to figure out

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), tableLayoutA.getHeight()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In toast it was showing me 0. I could not get why, although I have fixed the size for tableLayoutA in the xml itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Anyway me i understand by dynamic , when data keeps on changing in your TableLayout , is that what you are trying to say ? or

Comment: Can you please correct the code and post it so that i can get where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, At any instant the rows can be deleted added.

Comment: Mike.. thats has no effect at all

Comment: see in the another answer he used View.Layout.. I am totally confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table in real life needs at least one row and one column.
You didn't see the table, because you only created a row, but, there were no column.

You need to add a column to the row for something to be visible.

Try this :

```
  TextView label_date = new TextView(this);
    label_date.setText("DATE");
    label_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_date.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tableRow.addView(label_date);// add the column to the table row here

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You can replace the textView with whatever the value you want it to be.

```
tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Here what happens is, you say, add a view into tableLayout and you tell which view it is, and you also say the width and height of the view should wrap it's contents.

Also, specifying 40,70 is not a great idea, what happens when you have varying screen sizes. Furthermore, use a library to handle dynamic view addition and removal. You don't need to reinvent the wheel and save a lot of time and effort. For table views, https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout might be a good one (not sure). Another question is, is table view what you are looking for? Make sure you are not mistaking recyclerView for table views, I say this because I don't understand your use case.

Useful link : https://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/

Comment: Thats working. Can you please explain me what had happened.
Also explain how does this work --- tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: Why didn't you use TableRow.LayoutParams?

Comment: I want to fix row size to (70*40)dp how can I do that?

Comment: 1) Why didn't you use TableRow.LayoutParams? : Because it didn't seem to work.It might work, I don't know, but what I did, did work. 
 2) I want to fix row size to (70*40)dp how can I do that? you need to set table width and height as 70*40, set row width and height  as match parent and column heigh and width as wrap content(or match parent) and match parent, respectively.

Comment: It was not working either way. So insted of half dynamic layout I made it complete dynamic layout and now everything is working which I tried earlier and had not worked then.. :-/